# How to change color of multiple choice to show correct answer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

Im doing a multiple choice apps with 4 choices. How to prompt the user of the correct answer if he pressed the incorrect answer (at the same time).Here is a sample of the code.

```
        //Question/Answer options listener
        optionOne.setOnClickListener(this);     //On First Option selection
        optionTwo.setOnClickListener(this);     //On Second Option selection
        optionThree.setOnClickListener(this);   //On Third Option selection
        optionFour.setOnClickListener(this);    //On Forth Option selection

        skip.setOnClickListener(this);          //On Question Skip      
        pause.setOnClickListener(this);         //On Game Pause
        end.setOnClickListener(this);           //On Game End

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == optionOne.getId()){
            onOptionSelected(optionOne.getText().toString());
        }else if(v.getId() == optionTwo.getId()){
            onOptionSelected(optionTwo.getText().toString());
        }else if(v.getId() == optionThree.getId()){
            onOptionSelected(optionThree.getText().toString());
        }else if(v.getId() == optionFour.getId()){
            onOptionSelected(optionFour.getText().toString());
        }else if(v.getId() == pause.getId()){   //True when Game is Paused 

    //When an option of a question is selected
    private void onOptionSelected(String option){
        if(!isGamePaused && !isGameEnded) { //true when game is being played
            ATriviaQuestion tTQuestion = myListOfTriviaQuestions.get(currentQuestionNumber);
            if(option.equals(tTQuestion.GetOptions().get(tTQuestion.GetAnswer() - 1))) {
                correct += 1;
                remainingTime = mySecondsPassed;
                totalPoints += remainingTime * pointsPerRemainingSecond; 
                totalPoints += pointsPerCorrectAnswer;
            }
            else{
                incorrect += 1;
                totalPoints -= pointsPerWrongAnswer;
            }
```

I need to insert something on this portion to show the correct answer.

```
else{
    incorrect += 1;
    totalPoints -= pointsPerWrongAnswer;
    selectedOptionTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 

Here is my .plist
<question>
<key>Question</key>
<string>What is the ....</string>
<key>Options</key>
<array>
<string>option 1</string>
<string>option 2</string>
<string>option 3</string>
<string>option 4</string>
</array>
<key>Answer</key>
<integer>2</integer>
 </question>
```

Here is the other code

```
public ATriviaQuestion(){
    isThisQuestionAsked = false;
    answer = -1;
    answered = "";
}

public String GetQuestion()
{ return this.question; }

public void SetQuestion(String _question)
{ this.question=_question; }

public ArrayList<String> GetOptions()
{ return this.options; }

public void SetOptions(ArrayList<String> _options)
{ this.options = _options; }

public int GetAnswer()
{ return this.answer; }

public void SetAnswer(int _answer)
{ this.answer = _answer; }
```

Comment: please show all code that how you define the correct answer and All answer in what type of View.

Comment: are you using the options menu for your answer choice selections? If so I'd recommend using Views in your Layout instead of that.

Comment: @Anil. I just input the question, choices and correct answer in a .plist provided in the app. The scores updates when my answer is correct. What i want is to highlight the correct answer by changing its color to green and the rest to red for the user to know if he choose the correct answer.

Comment: @Tim. I just download it and its a full app, the only missing thing is i want to change the color of the choices to display the correct and wrong answer after answering the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way that I can see is to alter your onOptionSelected method to take the TextView as a parameter instead of just the string, you'll still be able to pull the string out in the same manner inside the method as you do outside of it now. And you'll have the reference that you need to change the background color.

```
//When an option of a question is selected
private void onOptionSelected(TextView selectedOptionTxt){
String option = selectedOptionTxt.getText().toString();

if(!isGamePaused && !isGameEnded) { //true when game is being played
    ATriviaQuestion tTQuestion = myListOfTriviaQuestions.get(currentQuestionNumber);
    if(option.equals(tTQuestion.GetOptions().get(tTQuestion.GetAnswer() - 1))) {
        correct += 1;
        remainingTime = mySecondsPassed;
        totalPoints += remainingTime * pointsPerRemainingSecond; 
        totalPoints += pointsPerCorrectAnswer;  
        selectedOptionTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else{
        incorrect += 1;
        totalPoints -= pointsPerWrongAnswer;
        selectedOptionTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

and then change where you are calling this method to pass the entire TextView instead of just the strings. like this:

```
onOptionSelected(optionOne);
```

note that you'll need to do this for each of the four, not just the one that I've shown here.

Comment: I have four errors saying "The method on onOptionSelected(TextView) is not applicable for the argument (String)"  

public void onClick(View v) {
  if(v.getId() == optionOne.getId()){
   onOptionSelected(optionOne.getText().toString());
  }else if(v.getId() == optionTwo.getId()){
   onOptionSelected(optionTwo.getText().toString());
  }else if(v.getId() == optionThree.getId()){
   onOptionSelected(optionThree.getText().toString());
  }else if(v.getId() == optionFour.getId()){
   onOptionSelected(optionFour.getText().toString());
  }else if(v.getId() == pause.getId()){

Comment: you need to remove the `.getText().toString()` portion inside all of your method calls to `onOptionSelected()` as I stated in the second part of my answer =). Also if you have code to post your should edity our question to post it so that it can be formatted properly, code in comments is a killer on the eyes!

Comment: It's working. :) But the green/red color do not disappear when the new question is presented automatically after answering. After 4 questions all the choices are either green or red. I want the colored background to disappear when the next question shows and also is it possible to show the correct(green) answer at the same time when I pick the wrong(red) answer, then both disappear when the next question comes. :)

Comment: so put `setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);` for all of your TextViews in the area of code where the new questions are asked from.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
        if(v.getId() == optionOne.getId()){
            onOptionSelected(optionOne.getText().toString(),v);
        }else if(v.getId() == optionTwo.getId()){
            onOptionSelected(optionTwo.getText().toString(),v);
        }else if(v.getId() == optionThree.getId()){
            onOptionSelected(optionThree.getText().toString(),v);
        }else if(v.getId() == optionFour.getId()){
            onOptionSelected(optionFour.getText().toString(),v);
        }else if(v.getId() == pause.getId())}

    private void onOptionSelected(String option,View v){
        if(!isGamePaused && !isGameEnded) { //true when game is being played
            ATriviaQuestion tTQuestion = myListOfTriviaQuestions.get(currentQuestionNumber);
            if(option.equals(tTQuestion.GetOptions().get(tTQuestion.GetAnswer() - 1))) {
                correct += 1;
                remainingTime = mySecondsPassed;
                totalPoints += remainingTime * pointsPerRemainingSecond; 
                totalPoints += pointsPerCorrectAnswer;  
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.id.greenBackground);
            }
            else{
                incorrect += 1;
                totalPoints -= pointsPerWrongAnswer;
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.id.redBackground);

            }
```

Where
`R.id.greenBackground` - ID of a drawable which you want to display behind the correct answer
`R.id.redBackground` - ID of a drawable which you want to display behind the wrong answer

Comment: R.id.greenBackground result to an error "cannot be resolved or not a field."

Comment: Same with Tim. Your code is working :). But the green/red color do not disappear when the new question is presented automatically after answering. After 4 questions all the choices are either green or red. I want the colored background to disappear when the next question shows and also is it possible to show the correct(green) answer at the same time when I pick the wrong(red) answer, then both disappear when the next question comes.